# How can I partialSign a v0 transaction which is using address lookup table?

Tags: web3.js

I am trying to replicate the following with VersionedTransaction -
Backedend API -

```
        transaction.partialSign(devWalletKey);
        let serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize({ requireAllSignatures: false });
        let transactionBase64 = serializedTransaction.toString("base64");

        return res.json({ success: true, transactionBase64 });
```

Frontend -

```
    let response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}withdrawToken`, { wallet: wallet.publicKey!.toBase58(), amount })

    let txn: string = response.data.transactionBase64

    let recoveredTxn = Transaction.from(Buffer.from(txn, 'base64'))
    let signedTxn = await wallet.signTransaction!(recoveredTxn)

    let tx = await solConnection.sendRawTransaction(signedTxn.serialize())
```

But with versioned transactions there is no partialSign method or serialize without requiring all signatures, so when I try to deserialize it I get an error saying **number of signers does not match**

So then how do you deal with versioned transactions that require more than one signature; where first is a keypair and the other is a web wallet?

Comment: You can make this work by hacking the library, but this should be possible without that -- please submit an issue about this! https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues

Comment: Yes, i have submitted an issue about this https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/28849

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to use the legacy deserializer with a versioned transaction. Versioned transactions use a different deserialization API than ‘legacy’ transactions.

### First determine whether a serialized transaction is ‘versioned’ or ‘legacy’

```
const serializedTransaction = '...';

// This will become either 'legacy' or a version number
const transactionVersion = VersionedMessage.deserializeMessageVersion(
  serializedTransaction,
);
```

### Then use the right deserialization strategy

```
if (transactionVersion === 'legacy') {
  const legacyTransaction = Transaction.from(serializedTransaction);
  legacyTransaction.partialSign(/* ... */);
} else {
  const versionedTransaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(serializedTransaction);
  versionedTransaction.sign([/* ... */]);
}
```

Comment: Executable code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-meadow-s2iors?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I will be using addressLookUpTables so the transaction is v1, what I don't understand is how can versionedTransactions be signed with a web wallet(like phantom) instead of a file wallet

Comment: Phantom supports versioned transactions now. https://twitter.com/bfriel_/status/1616258569611145216

Answer (score 0):

> Executable code example: codesandbox.io/s/billowing-meadow-s2iors?file=/src/index.js –

This doesn't work because VersionedTransaction.deserialize() checks the number of signatures.